# Node.js persistent data with cluster module

Tags: node.js, pm2

I've been reading [here](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/) and [here](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_how_it_works) about Node Js cluster module behaviour. I would like to quote [this article](https://medium.com/iquii/good-practices-for-high-performance-and-scalable-node-js-applications-part-2-3-2a68f875ce79):

> If you spawn multiple instances of your application, each process will
>   have its own memory space. This means that even if you are running on
>   a single machine, when you store some value in a global variable, or
>   more commonly a session in memory, you won’t find it there if the
>   balancer redirects you to another process during the next request.

My questions would be:

1. If storing some data in a plain simple Map like this:

   ```
   const userData = new Map();
   io.on("connection", socket => {
     socket.on("join", data => {
       const room = data.room;
       const username = data.username;
       userData.set(username, "some custom value")

       socket.join(room, error => {
         if (error) throw error;
         socket.emit("hello", userData);
       });
    });
   }
   ```

Will my data be persistent and available through my Node js app when use it like this?:

```
socket.on("anotherEvent", user => {
  socket.emit("whatever", userData.get(user));
});
```

2. Is it a good practice to use objects, Maps and arrays to store and share data in a Node js app when using pm2 in cluster mode?

I've always been using a database for this purpose. But I would like to know if it's possible to use built-in objects and arrays for some simple use cases.
Thanks for your support.

Comment: Bad idea! You should be using redis to store socket.io's sessions (with [socket.io-redis](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis)) and also to cache userdata

Comment: I've been reading about socket.io.redis. I'll give it a try. Thanks for your comment @rafaismyname

Comment: No problem! Wish you the best! Good luck! P.S.: Might worth to check if using firebase (for only this real time service) would be a better (and cheaper) idea ;)